# How would A* pathfinding in a maze deal with dead ends? (Pseudocode)

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking to the pseudocode for A* search on the following [tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/) (at the very bottom of the page). Am I correct in thinking that it doesn't account for hitting dead ends while it searches, and therefore having to backtrack from the dead end? If this isn't true, how does it take care of the dead ends? How would you take care of the dead ends otherwise?

Comment: You are looking for the shortest path.  In no static maze is the shortest path to go to a dead end and come back.  You are always better off as having not hit that dead end.  If you hit a dead end, stop processing that point.

Comment: Take a look at [this animation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Astar_progress_animation.gif) (from Wikipedia).

Also, here is the best [tutorial](http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm) on A* I ever saw.

Also, just in case, if you will need some working code, [here](https://gitorious.org/ballpath/ballpath/source/afa61d3a42ce07919dcdd129e622b606ec03ee71:src/core/pathfinder.cpp#L54) is a code in C++, that I wrote some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

It'll still work since there is no where for the algorithm to progress from that location. It will auto terminate that branch of the search tree.

Answer (score 2):

A* first searches for a way through the maze (The final path is not everything that was explored!).
Of course A* will explore dead ends and will backtrack.
When the algorithm finds the end, the algorithm terminates and the shortest path will not take dead ends into account.

Best regards,
Chris